# How to run Magento CLI command in docker Magento 2.4.4?

Tags: magento2, docker

I tried to run the Magento command in docker but am getting the error as per the screenshot.

Error ScreenShot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `sudo` command to run `bin/magento`. Maybe also check if you have the right permissions or that you followed the correct steps to install Magento? Also check if the database is correct and you docker instance can access it.